# Внести данные из словаря в словарь python

Tags: python, dict

Есть список кортежей с неопределенным количеством данных:

```
[('Главное меню',), ('О нас',), ('Фотографии',), ('Информация',) ...]
```

С таким примером на выходе нужно получить такой словарь:

```
{'one_time': False, 'buttons': 

[[{'action': 
{'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': 'Главное меню'}, 'color': 'negative'}, {'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "2"}', 'label': 'О нас'}, 'color': 'positive'}],

[{'action':
{'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "3"}', 'label': 'Фотографии'}, 'color': 'default'}, {'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "4"}', 'label': 'Информация'}, 'color': 'primary'}]]}
```

Как можно это реализовать и что использовать? Пытался при помощи циклов, но быстро запутался.

Comment: Во-первых, у вас есть не словарь, а список кортежей. Во-вторых, объясните подробнее принцип по которому должны быть преобразованы данные.

Comment: Исправил. Нужно чтобы полученные элемент кортежа, например "Главное меню" и «О нас» оборачивались в 
[[{'action': 
{'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': 'Главное меню'}, 'color': 'negative'}, {'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "2"}', 'label': 'О нас'}, 'color': 'positive'}],

Но если их больше двух (как в моем случае) то создавался еще один  

[[{'action': 
{'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': ‘Фотографии'}, 'color': 'negative'}, {'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "2"}', 'label': ‘Информация’}, 'color': 'positive'}],

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вставить значения из списка кортежей в словарь? Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893277/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c-python)

Answer (score 1):

Так попробуйте (особо не проверял, только как путь решения):

```py
l = [('Главное меню',), ('О нас',), ('Фотографии',), ('Информация',)]
d = {'one_time': False, 'buttons': [[ {'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': label[0]}, 'color': 'primary'} for label in l]]}
print(d)
```

> {'one_time': False, 'buttons': [[{'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': 'Главное меню'}, 'color': 'primary'}, {'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': 'О нас'}, 'color': 'primary'}, {'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': 'Фотографии'}, 'color': 'primary'}, {'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': 'Информация'}, 'color': 'primary'}]]}