# Как вставить значения из списка кортежей в словарь? Python

Tags: python, dict

Есть список кортежей:

```
rows = [('Главное меню',), ('О нас',), ('Фотографии',), ('Новости',)]
```

Каждое значение (Например Главное меню) нужно добавить в такой словарь:

```
{'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': 'Главное меню'}, 'color': 'primary'}
```

И на выходе сложить в единый словарь чтобы получилось:

```
    mydict = {'one_time': False, 'buttons': [[

   [{'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': 'Главное меню'}, 'color': 'primary'}

   {'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': 'О нас'}, 'color': 'primary'}]



    [{'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': 'Фотографии'}, 'color': 'primary'}

    {'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': 'Новости'}, 'color': 'primary'}]

    ]]}
```

Comment: `mydict = {'one_time': False, 'buttons': [[
{'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}', 'label': label[0]}, 'color': 'primary'}
for label in rows
]]}` - вроде так. Кстатит, в `'buttons': [[`\` - так и должно быть, именно список из одного элемента, являющего списком?

Comment: В списке кортежей всегда по одному значению? И ещё - словарь на выходе некорректен - items нужно разделять запятыми.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо обычное присвоение значения ключу и цикл по списку:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import copy
rows = [('Главное меню',), ('О нас',), ('Фотографии',), ('Новости',)]
q = {'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}',
                'label': 'Главное меню'}, 'color': 'primary'}
mydict = {'one_time': False, 'buttons': [[]]}
two_list = []
for t in rows:
    new_q = copy.deepcopy(q)
    new_q['action']['label'] = t[0]
    two_list.append(new_q)
    if len(two_list) == 2:
        mydict['buttons'][0].append(two_list)
        two_list = []
mydict['buttons'][0].append(two_list)
print mydict
```

Comment: проверьте свой код. Когда я его запускаю - три раза "Фотографии"

Comment: поправил, словари тянулись из одного места...

Comment: Спасибо за решение, может еще подскажите как можно модифицировать этот код чтобы каждые два значения он оборачивал в [ ]? (Дописал в вопросе пример)

Comment: @CoffeeinTime добавил

Comment: А только вот если значений 5, то последнее куда-то пропадает. хотелось бы чтобы если оставалось 1 значение в конце то оно тоже оборачивалось в []

Comment: добавил... если еще будет что-то непонятно, то лучше откройте новый вопрос