# Spyder - разный результат с отладкой и без. Ошибка оболочки?

Tags: python, отладка, spyder

Есть код, взятый из ответа [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893277/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-python), но это не важно для вопроса:

```
from  pprint import pprint

rows = [('Главное меню',), ('О нас',), ('Фотографии',)]
q = {'action': {'type': 'text', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}',
                'label': 'Главное меню'}, 'color': 'primary'}
mydict = {'one_time': False, 'buttons': [[]]}

for t in rows:
    new_q = q
    new_q['action']['label'] = t[0]
    mydict['buttons'][0].append(new_q)

pprint (mydict)
```

если я его запускаю без отладки, получаю везде `'label': 'Фотографии'`:

```
{'buttons': [[{'action': {'label': 'Фотографии',
                          'payload': '{"button": "1"}',
                          'type': 'text'},
               'color': 'primary'},
              {'action': {'label': 'Фотографии',
                          'payload': '{"button": "1"}',
                          'type': 'text'},
               'color': 'primary'},
              {'action': {'label': 'Фотографии',
                          'payload': '{"button": "1"}',
                          'type': 'text'},
               'color': 'primary'}]],
 'one_time': False}
```

Если же запускаю под отладчиком и - внимание - смотрю на словарь, докапываясь до `'label':` в закладке "Менеджер переменных", то начиная с того места, где я посмотрел - начинает работать по-другому.  Например так:

```
{'buttons': [[{'action': {'label': 'О нас',
                          'payload': '{"button": "1"}',
                          'type': 'text'},
               'color': 'primary'},
              {'action': {'label': 'О нас',
                          'payload': '{"button": "1"}',
                          'type': 'text'},
               'color': 'primary'},
              {'action': {'label': 'Фотографии',
                          'payload': '{"button": "1"}',
                          'type': 'text'},
               'color': 'primary'}]],
 'one_time': False}
```

Однако, до того как я посмотрел, получаю везде `'label': 'О нас'`:
Что за кошка Шредингера?

Итак вопрос - *если это повторяется и на вашем компьютере, то как тогда можно отлаживать код в такой ситуации? Наверное стоит написать в Spyder или я чего то не понимаю?*

Comment: Вы учитываете, что при операции `new_q = q` не происходит копирования словаря? Каждый раз это один и тот же словарь.

Comment: Да, я обратил на это внимание автора решения и в указанном вопросе он изменил код на глубокое копирование. НО! @insolor вопрос в другом. Почему, когда я пользуюсь просмотром переменных в Спайдере все меняется, как будто наблюдение меняет тип копирования что ли.
То есть если я в цикле буду смотреть на `label`, присвоение пройдет нормально. Что ж это за отладка тогда.
Можете повторить в Спайдере, если он у вас есть?

Comment: У меня в `mydict` на второй итерации лежит такое: `{'one_time': False, 'buttons': [[{'action': {'type': 'text', 'label': 'О нас', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}'}, 'color': 'primary'}, {'action': {'type': 'text', 'label': 'О нас', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}'}, 'color': 'primary'}]]}` (Spyder3, pdb)

Comment: А на третьей итерации - `[[{'action': {'type': 'text', 'label': 'О нас', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}'}, 'color': 'primary'}, {'action': {'type': 'text', 'label': 'О нас', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}'}, 'color': 'primary'}, {'action': {'type': 'text', 'label': 'Фотографии', 'payload': '{"button": "1"}'}, 'color': 'primary'}]]`

Comment: @Anton - ну вот и получается что при просмотре переменных меняется результат выполнения кода )))

Comment: Похоже на то. Ещё, что интересно, если выводить `print(id(mydict['buttons'][0][0]))`, `print(id(mydict['buttons'][0][1]))`, `print(id(mydict['buttons'][0][2]))` - то получится три одинаковых числа, а если на втором шаге посмотреть в оладчике на mydict, вышло `139986572658184 139986572658184 139986572542984`, т.е. 2 первых равны, а третий id - нет. Выводить - в смысле после `pprint (mydict)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная ошибка устранена в версиях Spyder 3.1 и выше.